# Merging cells with same content on Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a table which looks like this (I blurred some private content but it's mock data so rest is enough to understand the situation)

[image: table]

As you can see there are repeated infos on columns and on some columns I have to merge 5 cells but on the other I have to merge 3.

I want to know if there's an easy way to merge cells. For example, I want to show 1 simulator supervision cell, not 6.

The point calculation and stuff is kinda more complicated so I won't share the whole code but for the projectname, description and deadline columns, here is the code to show them on screen:

```
      <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let subtaskclones of overviewStcs">
      <td>{{ subtaskclones.taskName }} </td>
      <td>{{ subtaskclones.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ subtaskclones.deadline | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</td>
```

I'm getting all the necessary data from an API. So data here is not hardcoded.

Comment: `Simulator Supervision` is repeated across rows. Do you mean to merge rows?

Comment: Yeah I meant rows. @ChristianVincenzoTraina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier when you use libraries like [material-angular](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) or [ngx-datable](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/)

In your case, you need to process the data of the table before render it. You need to sort the date and calculate the row span of each column.

For example, something like this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxef8b?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that I've made.

Comment: Thanks for effort, it was very useful for me to understand. Code didn't worked for me tho, I've tried to implement it to my own code but I assume I'm doing something wrong while getting data from API. Anyways, I understand the way to do it, so thanks again.

Comment: Update: I've understand your logic and wrote completely new function for my project. Works perfectly. Since I had more fields in project than I showed in here it took some time but worth it!